# Task management software that will sync with GTasks and exchange?

Tags: exchange-tasks, google-tasks

I am trying desparately to find an app solution to manage all of my disparate task lists. I work for two companies, both supply me with exchange credentials and a phone (one iphone, one blackberry). Both sites run through exchange. My personal device is a Samsung Galaxy S3.

For personal tasks I have been using Astrid, but I am unable to get my outlook tasks that way. I have heard people suggest using touchdown, but that would create yet another task manager that I'd have to tangle with. The solution I am looking for is something that would either:

1. Sync exchange at each site to google tasks, which astrid would then sync on to my personal device.
2. Allow astrid to directly pull down tasks from the exchange servers
3. Provide some other 3rd party task manager which would sync with google tasks, and both exchange servers.

I am using a mac, so sadly the outlook sync for google apps program won't work (it's windows only, and only compatible with the windows version of outlook).

Any recommendations on how to accomplish what I'm doing? Right now I am missing tasks because I have to juggle 3 different devices to get everything, and it's having a pretty big impact on my productivity.

Comment: I would also be very interested in such a solution.  Right now I make do with [GTasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dayup.gtask) for Google tasks, and [TaskSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.cranktheory.android.tasks) for Exchange tasks.